# How define_method uses variables initialised outside of it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

```
class Temp1
  def add(s)
    match = 'test'
    self.class.class_eval do
       define_method(s) do
         puts match
       end
    end
    #match ='haha'
  end
end
```

As i thinks of it, 'match' is a local variable, so i don't understand how it can see it from another method, plus if uncomment #match ='haha', method will print 'haha' somehow. Can somebody explain it?

Also, i don't see difference here between using class_eval or instance_eval, seems like it do the same thing.

And, at last but not least, can I create class method here using define_method? So I can call it like Temp1.something instead of Temp1.new.something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Because blocks (do...end) are closures and have access to their
surrounding scope.**

You used block with `class_eval`,so it has the access to its surroundings,which is the scope of the method `add`. Now you use another block with `define_method`,which as also has the access to the scope of the method `add`,via the block with the `class_eval`.`match` local variable has been created inside the scope of the method `add`. So the blocks has the access to the variable.

> And, at last but not least, can I create class method here using define_method?

No you can't.[`define_method`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method) *Defines an instance method in the receiver*.`self.class` is `Temp1`. Now under `Temp1.class_eval do..end`,you are defining instance methods of the class `Temp1`,with the method `define_method`.`define_method` is a private class method of all the classes,in which ancestor chain `Object` class present.

```
class C;end
C.private_methods.grep(/define_/)
# => [:define_method]
```

> Also, i don't see difference here between using [class_eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) or [instance_eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval), seems like it do the same thing.

Okay! Let me explain for you. You can't see the difference here,as `Teamp1` is a `Class` and also an instance of a `Class`. In both call `class_eval` and `instance_eval`,`self` is being set to `Teamp1`,by their respective definition as documented.

```
class C
  def self.bar;11;end
  def baz;12;end
end

C.is_a? Class # => true
C.instance_of? Class # => true

C.class_eval{ bar } # => 11
C.instance_eval{ bar } # => 11
```

Hope this helps!